# Elasticsearch Bulk Response with Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have the following Python code to do a ElasticSearch batch update, and when I get back the response object, I got something very simple, and it doesn't look right to me, anything wrong here?

```
...
actions = []
for item in data:
    actions.append({"_index": index,
                    "_type": doc_type,
                    "_id": item['id'],
                    "_source": item})

print ("batching result")
response = helpers.bulk(self.es.conn, actions)
print (response)
```

Here is the output, but I'm expecting something more detail.

```
batching result
(2, [])
```

Comment: This is normal. From the [docs](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk): "It returns a tuple with summary information - number of successfully executed actions and either list of errors or number of errors if `stats_only` is set to True"

Comment: What if we want to get the same response as when the bulk API is called from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in [documentation](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk):

> It returns a tuple with summary information - number of successfully executed actions and either list of errors or number of errors if stats_only is set to True
>   [...] If you need to process a lot of data and want to ignore/collect errors please consider using the streaming_bulk() helper which will just return the errors and not store them in memory.

with streaming_bulk() you have to use `raise_on_error` parameter for raise on error.
if you want to collect a lot of data i suggest to use [parallel_bulk()](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/helpers-parallel-bulk-in-python-not-working/39498/2) that is faster and more intuitive